# xlwings pandas slice error on save

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
\\path\Main.py:157: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  linked_performance['GICS Ind Weight'] = 100*linked_performance['Average % Weight Port']/linked_performance['Average % Weight Port'].sum()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "\\path\Main.py", line 174, in main
    wb.save('\\path\current_report.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 287, in save
    xlplatform.save_workbook(self.xl_workbook, path)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-pack
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Where like 174 is:

```
wb.save('\\path\current_report.xlsx')
```

If I do not save, I do not get the error.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: Can you post a minimal code sample to reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: adding `.copy()` fixed it. but thank you for looking.

Comment: `linked_performance = p.df_holding[(p.df_holding.Sector==sector) & (p.df_holding.Industry == industry)].copy()`